# i have a error with TRIGGER in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `STUDENTS` (`ID, NAME, BIRTHDAY`) and I want to use trigger for constraint input data, do not allow input data for `NAME` column duplicate

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEST
ON STUDENTS
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM inserted 
               WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME
                              FROM STUDENTS))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Duplicated'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
    END
END
```

and more

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEST
ON STUDENTS
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NAME nvarchar(15)

    SELECT @NAME = NAME
    FROM inserted

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE NAME = @NAME)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Duplicated'
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
END
```

but, 2 method above, it's return error 'Duplicated', although input data is not duplicate. I do not know where error, I think because 'EXISTS'

Help me, thanks so much ^_^

Comment: The trigger gets run after the insert so the value will already be in the table.  You need application or stored procedures to check before the insert or create an index/constraint on name that does not allow duplicates.

Comment: use [unique constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) instead of trigers

Comment: @Hogan trigger could be before insert but for that constraint should fix it

Comment: Your trigger logic has a MAJOR flaw. It assume there will only be a single row inserted. This needs to be rewritten as a set based approach.

Comment: @profesor79 there is no before trigger in sql server. There is only AFTER and INSTEAD OF.

Comment: @SeanLange - that's true - just naming - the hardest thing in it - thanks for pointing that.

Comment: ... names are not unique.  At all.  This is doomed to blow up on you real fast.  Why are you trying to prevent 'duplicate' names?  What is it you're actually trying to prevent?

Comment: i used INSTEAD OF INSERT replace for FOR INSERT

CREATE TRIGGER TEST
ON STUDENTS
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM inserted 
               WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME
                              FROM STUDENTS))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Duplicated'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
    END
END
it's working, but record inserted in table , not display although i refreshed table, and sql notifycain ... arow(s) affected and data input do not duplicate, help me tks